# CSS not loading in safari, working fine everywhere else

Tags: android, html, css, safari, loading

The CSS of a website I've developed doesn't seem to load in Safari. I have tested the syntax and there are no errors. Same for the HTML.
Also on a mobile Samsung Android, it doesn't load all the time.

Here's the website : http://twennys.com/

**Update:**
So I have feedback from my friend:
He is getting a "Failed to load resource: the network connection was lost" for every resource files (css and js). I've looked for solution online but could'nt find anything that solved the problem...

Comment: First of all, in what part of your website where css is not working in safari? all of your css? I'm kinda confuse because its working fine in my safari

Comment: Yes all of the css.
One of the difficulty for me is that the problem occured on my friend (who I made the website for) iMac, on my mac book pro it is working fine... I told him to empty is cache but he still has the problem... 
The problem persists on my samsung though.

Answer (score -1):

I can see you are referring the style-sheet in link like this

```
<link href="/css-simplegrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Can you try removing the forward slash from the href and link like this

```
<link href="css-simplegrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Because when you put forward slash, there is a chance for safari taking it as

```
http://twennys.com//css-simplegrid.min.css
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work... Still have the same problem on my Samsung (using chrome app by the way). Unfortunately I can't try for safari as the problem occured on my friends iMac